# Calling Java Web service from C# returns null always

Tags: service

I am trying to call Java webservice from C#. The results are always null.
Can anyone help why it is returnign null values.
(When i test the webservice from soap ui. it is returning values.)
am i missing anything?

Comment: How are you consuming the webservice in C#?  How are you deserializing the object?

Comment: var unitLists = new UnitsList();
            unitLists = RequestType.UnitRequest;

            var unitRecs = new List<UnitRec>();
            unitRecs = unitLists.Units;
            
            var Service = new Service1();

            var unitsListObj = new unitsList();

            var unitsListObj2 = new unitsList();

            unitsListObj.transactionID = unitLists.TransactionID;
            
            unitsListObj.units = unitRecs.ToArray();


            unitsListObj2 = Service.process(unitsListObj);

Comment: do i need to add anything else to consume java services.

Comment: Can you edit the original post to contain the code of the Service1 class?

Comment: service1 class is the one we consume..we dont have the code..

Comment: I still need to see the code where you are actually calling the web service itself.  If that is wrapped in another class, you need to understand what it is doing.  It sounds like the code that makes the call to the webservice is failing.  Any .NET language is fully capable of consuming Java web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used the wrong proxy. my bad